# Copy first array value to another field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an old list of products that store the descriptions in an array at index [0]. The model is set up as a string. So my plan is to extract that value and add it to a temporary field. Step 2 would be to take that value and copy it to the original field.
This is the 'wrong' product I want to fix.

```
{_id : 1 , pDescription : ['great product']},
{_id : 2 , pDescription : ['another product']}
```

All I want to is to change the array to a string like this:

```
{_id : 1 , pDescription : 'great product'},
{_id : 2 , pDescription : 'another product'}
```

I have tried this to create the temporary description:

```
    Products.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            pDescription: {
                $type: "array"
            }
        }
        },
    {
        $set: {
            pDescTemp: {
                $first: "$pDescription"
            }
        }
            }
        ]).exec((err, r) => {
       // do stuff here
   });
```

The command works fine without the `$first` command.
The error reads: `MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$first'`

Any tips on how to fix this are appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you need to update your `pDescription` field to be equal to the first element of the array already stored as `pDescription`:

```
db.Products.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      pDescription: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$pDescription",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much codemonkey!!

Comment: @Caldera500 No problem. Just remember that aggregation in and of itself does not update anything, it's just a tool to accumulate and display data, so `Products.aggregate` is not the way to go. Rather you need an aggregation *pipeline* inside an update operator.

Comment: This makes totally sense. During my research I found out that you can combine aggregation with updates. I guess this is mostly used for other applications. The update call you are describing is much better for my use case. Also extremely elegant and fast. I updated 5k document in less than 0.5 secs. The Mongo docs usually only show the most basic use cases. I guess I still have much to learn here. Thanks again!

Comment: How would it need to be altered to store the first element not onto the source itself but to another field? I tried the above but got *The dollar ($) prefixed field '$arrayElemAt' in 'plonk.$arrayElemAt' is not valid for storage*. Here, `plonks` is my array to copy the first element from and `plonk` is the field to store it in.

Comment: @KonradViltersten If I understand you correctly, here is what you need: https://mongoplayground.net/p/iiEkmA8ecMU