# How to copy a value from an array to another field and then pop it?

Tags: mongodb

Assume we have inserted the following object.

```
db.getCollection('things').insert(
  { plonks: [ "plonk1", "plonk2", "plonk3" ], _id: 1001 } 
)
```

I can update the document and insert a new field like so.

```
db.getCollection('things').update(
  { _id: 1001 },
  { $set: { plonk: "beep" } }
)
```

I can also pop the latest addition like this.

```
db.getCollection('things').update(
  { _id: 1001 },
  { $pop: { plonks: 1 } }
)
```

Now, I'd like to connect those two operations somehow so that the popped element will be set as a value in the separate field. I want to end up in a document looking as follows.

```
{
  _id: 1001,
  plonk: "plonk3",
  plonks: [ "plonk1", "plonk2" ]
}
```

There's nothing on fetching/storageing the popped value in the [docs for `$pop`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/). I've seen [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947354/1525840) to a similar question, which didn't work out as they're copying the element onto itself, reducing the original array. I tried reading up on [`$aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) as I sensed that let me provide a list of operations but I'm fumbling in darkness without any method of approach.

I also tried with a combination of `$match` and `$set` getting a bit success when copying over the **whole** array like this.

```
db.getCollection('things').aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1001 } },
  { $set: { plonk: "$plonks" } }
])
```

However, I haven't got the [`$slice`ing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) to work.

```
db.getCollection('things').aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1001 } },
  { $set: { plonk: { plonks: { $slice: 1 } } } }
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline support for update command feature.

> Note: This will work only on MongoDB version >= 4.2

For `plonk` key, make use of `$arrayElemAt` to fetch the last element of the array

For `plonks` key, use `$slice` accumulator, where the `position` option is the size of plonks array - 1

```
db.getCollection('things').update({
  "plonks": {"$exists": true},  // Find Conditions
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "plonk": {  // Fetch last element from `plonks` array
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$plonks",
          -1
        ]
      },
      "plonks": {
        "$slice": [  // Get elements from array till n-1
          "$plonks",
          {
            "$subtract": [
              {
                "$size": "$plonks"  // Fetches size of `plonks` array
              },
              1
            ]
          },
        ],
      },
    }
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jNCPhh0DdkE)

Comment: I see no occurrence of `$pop`. How come? Is it not available for this particular circumstances? Or is in uncertain that the order of the elements in the array can be ensured?

Comment: `$pop` is an array update command and won't work here since everything inside `[]` will only support Aggregation pipelines and Aggregation Accumulators. `$set` of Update and Aggregation are a bit different (It's a bit confusing since MongoDB wanted to support aggregation pipelines in the update but messed up a bit in my opinion, confusing developers).  The `{}` is for find conditions. Apply conditions as you would do for a normal update command.

Comment: Also, you have an empty object as the first element of the `update()` method. I noticed that I need to set it to `{ _id: 1001 }` to only match my regarded document. However, it surprised me that I can't use `{ $match: { _id: 1001 } }`. What do I miss, please?

Comment: Oh, I see your comment now. Is it the case that `$match` also isn't a part of update pipy?

Comment: `$match` won't work. As I said, MongoDB messed up. Only a hand few Aggregation pipelines are supported. Read more about this feature and list of supported Pipeline stages here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/   Hope this helped you. I have added a bit of verbosity in the code in my answer,

Comment: This answer rocks. I can confirm it works and is clearly explained. It takes an hour or so to grasp it but that's more about my intellectual limitation than your contribution. It's +1 for extra effort explaining quirks and such. One FUQ - I noticed that you had quotation marks around all the operators while I can skip them (only enclosing the field names). Is there a specific though behind that? Any recommendation?

Comment: I am very glad that my answer helped you, sir. I write code in python using the `PyMongo` package. Operators which are not enclosed by quotation marks will work only on Mongo Shell. The moment I start writing code in a driver (or at least in PyMongo in my case), I have to include quotation marks since the programming language doesn't understand Mongo Operators. So, I made it a habit to enclose MongoDB Pipelines, Operators, and Accumulators with single or double quotes wherever possible.

Comment: Also, while using keys/variables with `$` and `$$` prefixes respectively, it will throw an error in Mongo Shell, since they are not recognized by MongoDB validators. So better make it a habit so that there is no need to guess if you have to include Quotes and also, you can directly copy that code to the programming language of your choice without having to deal with adding quotes manually for every operator I used.